# Highchart Zoom issue in mobile browser

Tags: mobile, highcharts, candlestick-chart, zoom-sdk, pinch

Greetings,
I'm writing this to request you for support to solve an issue of mobile browsing. We're using multiple types of charts in the same chart simultaneously. Here, the details are as follows:
- Candlestick, Lines, Column, Scatter plot, Plotlines.
-  We've applied these types of charts to the same chart. Please find an attachment for your reference with the code.
We're waiting for your response. THANK YOU.

Every feature is working well except the zoom issue in the mobile browser. When we try to pinch in or out in mobile mode, it's an issue in the view of candles. Here is the link and code to our chart URL.

Comment: Hi @Krupali Clavier, it seems you received support on our GitHub channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/19728. For future questions, please remember to add the [highcharts] tag when referring to Highcharts. Regards!